# Rewriting urls to cut out one directory level in combined django/wordpress setup

Tags: django, wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting, virtualhost

I have a webserver that serves from django and wordpress for the same site/domain. So there are python/django pages served using mod_wsgi and php/wordpress pages using mod_php. This is all set up and works fine.

The condensed (for this question I removed mappings to static files/folders and logging configuration) virtualhost config looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com

    # root directory mapped to djangos wsgi file
    WSGIScriptAlias / /opt/examplecom/example.wsgi

    <Directory /opt/examplecom>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    # a subdirectory mapped to wordpress installation folder
    Alias /wp/ /var/www/examplewp/
    <Location "/var/www/examplewp/">
            Options -Indexes
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

This serves everything from django, except all that is requested from the `/wp/` subdirectory. E.g. `www.example.com/about/` is served from django, `example.com/wp/terms` is served from wordpress.

Now, what I want to do, is rewrite all urls that point to something in the `/wp/` subdirectory, so they look like it is in the root directory. E.g. `example.com/wp/terms` shall be rewritten to `example.com/terms`.

As far as I understand that matter there are some specialities:

1. The easiest thing, using an alias `Alias / /var/www/examplewp/` can not be done, because the root directory is already mapped to the wsgi-script.
2. Wordpress does its own rewriting. `example.com/wp/terms` is a rewrite of `example.com/wp/index.php?p=33`. Wordpress rewrite config is stored in an .htaccess file in its installation folder.

I tried something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com

    RewriteEngin On
    RewriteRule ^/wp/terms$ /terms

    # root directory mapped to djangos wsgi file
    WSGIScriptAlias / /opt/examplecom/example.wsgi

    <Directory /opt/examplecom>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    # a subdirectory mapped to wordpress installation folder
    Alias /wp/ /var/www/examplewp/
    <Location "/var/www/examplewp/">
            Options -Indexes
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

but this does not do anything. And I have no clue where to start to test what is faulty.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngin On
RewriteRule ^/wp/terms$ /terms  [L]
```

Frankly speaking this wont work because  **^/wp/terms$**  translate to **/terms** and serve by **mod_wsgi**.